# nativescript wait for request until vuex complete request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

I have page Login.vue and I am using a strategy if the user already logged in then go to Home Component else stay same

My Code

```
mounted() {
  this.checkAlreadyLoggedIn();
},
methods: { 
 async checkAlreadyLoggedIn() {
   this.busy = true;
   await this.$store.dispatch("attempt");
   this.busy = false;
   if (this.$store.getters.loggedIn) {
     this.$navigateTo(Home, {
      clearHistory: true
     });
   }
 },
}
```

attempt action request to server and get users detail
but it seems it triggers `this.$store.getters.loggedIn` early

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to wait properly before checking the getter, and trigger the busy state, return the promise from the `attempt` action:

```js
attempt({ state, commit }) {
  return axios.post(...)  // <-- Returning the promise manually
  .then(response => {
    // Commit change
  })
},
```

Or with async / await:

```js
async attempt({ state, commit }) { // <-- async keyword returns promise automatically
  const response = await axios.post(...);
  // Commit change
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/1s8pdgfb/)